# Create a shortcut for application on Google Chrome for MacOSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome, shortcuts

Google Chrome on Windows comes with a very usefull feature allowing the user to *Create application shortcuts* from the settings menu: http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95710

Unfortunately there is not such feature on Google Chrome for MacOSX. Is there a trick to enable this feature? An hidden menu? Is it on the developpement list?

Comment: What do you mean by a shorcut application?
A shortcut (alias) that would direct to Google Chrome itself?
Or a shortcut to open an url directly from desktop? (called .webloc files, should be avaible when saving webpage)

Comment: I had the application shortcut reference: it's a feature on chrome for windows.

Comment: Then if you're looking for the website alias to desktop, like .webloc files, the simple way is to drag and drop favicon from URL bar to Desktop, with Command Key pressed ! :)

Otherwhise, if you're looking for something like Prism for Firefox, I didn't find anything for Chrome…

Comment: Forget my comment just above, started replying before leaving and didn't saw your edit with link, sorry!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Applicationize

Applicationize is an open-source, free service I built that replicates the "Create Application Shortcuts" behavior on Mac by generating a Chrome Extension of your favorite website on-the-fly that opens in its own window with its own dock icon!

https://applicationize.me/

https://github.com/eladnava/applicationize

Answer (score 3):

Here is a little more simpler method using [createGcApp](https://github.com/maxkostow/createchromeapp) application.

> In addition to giving it a much more familiar interface, it also fixes
>   some of the bugs in the previous script such as those preventing
>   spaces in application names. The usage of the new version of the tool
>   should be pretty straight forward. Start by downloading the .dmg, and
>   opening the image. Inside, you should find a readme file, a script
>   called createGcApp, and the source folder. Double-clicking the script
>   will prompt you with questions about name, url, and icon for the
>   application shortcut (make sure it's a square if you include an icon).
>   The resulting file will then be saved to the /Applications folder.
>   Thanks so much to Mait for sharing this much easier version.

Screenshot for how it looks:

[image]

Comment: welcome to Super User! link-only answers are generally discouraged here (what if the linked page becomes unavailable?), would you consider editing your answer to summarize the procedure?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution: 
http://lifehacker.com/5611711/create-application-shortcuts-in-google-chrome-for-mac-with-a-shell-script

Basically a script is creating a proper icon in the application with the 3 following parameters:

- Application name
- Application URL
- Logo path

It works almost like on Windows except that external link are open in a internal tab.

Comment: Works well except for the media keys does not work for such an app (e. g. for Google Music), but you can download an extension for that in a new tab of the app https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/key-socket-media-keys/fphfgdknbpakeedbaenojjdcdoajihik?hl=en

Comment: note:"any Google Chrome preferences and extensions won't carry over, since this creates a new Chrome profile each time."